# Python code to move file over socket

Tags: python

SO family, I trying to write an application where i can transfer files between two computers.  I currently this working using something like this:

On client side

```
file = open(srcfile, 'r')
content = file.read()
file.close()
send_message(srcfile)
send_message(content)
```

On Server side:

```
filename = receive_message(message)
content = receive_message(message)          
file = open(filename, 'w')
file.write(content)
file.close()
```

This seems to work for text files, but for other file types it doesn't work..

I'm thinking there has to be a better way.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use

```
file = open(srcfile, 'rb')
```

and

```
file = open(srcfile, 'wb')
```

respectivly ... the `b` means binary...

Comment: Well that answers my question of "would binary mode work." Didn't want to answer that and look dumb when it was wrong.

Comment: heh im pretty sure thats the problem ... I know sockets in general have no problem with binary data

Comment: It was that simple! Thanks!